# Como eu crio um parametro opcional

Tags: javascript, funções

Como posso definir o o segundo paramentro "&& bonus2" como opcional ?

Quero que o if rode das maneiras:
(bonus1 && bonus2 == true) ou
(bonus1 == true)

Precisa ser uma parametro que se eu colocar na função ele aceite e rode, se eu não colocar continuo normalmento, não é um valor predefino.

```js
function offersFixed(bonus1, bonus2, textValue ){
        if (bonus1 && bonus2 == true ){        

        var valide = document.getElementById("valideorNot");
        valide.setAttribute("class", "invalidPass")
        valide.textContent = "Oferta Inválida";

        var textId = document.getElementById("validateResult");
        var createText = document.createElement("h3");
        createText.textContent = textValue;
        textId.appendChild(createText);
                 
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Se bonus2 é opcional, não faz sentido `(bonus1 && bonus2 == true)`

Comment: Se bonus2 é opcional, pra quê verificar ele? A não ser que dentro do if ele vá influenciar em algo. Aí você deveria fazer um outro if dentro do if.

Comment: Nao devia ser um OR? `if (bonus1 === true || bonus2)`? Só vai verificar bonus2 se bonus1 nao for true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece-me que há várias possibilidades aqui, mas que não queres entrar no if caso `bonus1` ou `bonus2` seja false.

Se `bonus2` é opcional, podes definir o seu valor para `true` por omissão.

```
function offersFixed(bonus1, bonus2, textValue ){
  // se passar false para bonus2, entao vai ser false, senão será sempre true
  bonus2 = (bonus2 === false) ? false : true;
  if (bonus1 === true && bonus2){
  // ... etc
```

## Parametros opcionais

Uma alteração que fazia ao código seria mover o que é opcional para o fim da lista de parâmetros. 
Como está agora, caso `bonus2` não esteja presente, ainda tens de passar um valor, mesmo que seja null, e a chamada fica assim

```
offersFixed(true, null, 'O valor de textValue');
```

Se mudares a assinatura da função para

```
function offersFixed(textValue, bonus1, bonus2)
```

vais poder chamar assim

```
offersFixed('O valor de textValue', true);
```

E podes usar o código fornecido no topo da resposta para `bonus2` ser sempre `true`, excepto quando passas `false`.
Assim.

```
offersFixed('O valor de textValue', true, false);
```